# mysqldump 5.7.24 error with openssl 1.1 at MacOS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, openssl

I have a **Ruby on Rails v6 on Ruby 2.6.3** application connected to **MySQL 5.7.x** run on **MacOS Catalina**.

I have to use the **mysql2 0.5.3 gem**, because 0.5.2 does not work on Ruby >= 2.6.

The **mysql2 0.5.3 needs openssl >= 1.1, but mysqldump 5.7.x needs openssl 1.0**.

I have already uninstall openssl 1.1, and install 1.0, but I need mysql2 0.5.3 and mysqldump 5.7.x run at the "sametime".

May anybody help me?

Comment: My local mysql is 8.x (and runs mysqldump ok), but, as mysqldump 8.x does not dump MySQL 5.x. The error is: **(exit 134)Error retrieving version from /usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.24/bin/mysqldump:
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your MySql to 5.7.28 and it is work. Thanks Oracle.